# How do I debug Uglify parse errors?

Tags: javascript, uglifyjs, uglifyjs2

I'm uglifying a JS file and just started getting

```
DEBUG: { message: 'Unexpected token: name (a)',
  line: 1,
  col: 17726,
  pos: 17726
```

What are the debugging steps I need to follow to track this down?

Needless to say, I've tried the obvious stuff like searching for "name" and "(a)", neither of which appear in the file. It would also be helpful to see what "line:1 col: 17726" are referring to since my input file is beautiful JS.

Comment: Try generating source maps to track the original code. It is unlikely an Uglify issue, but some library you use isn't playing nice with minification. Are you using Angular?

Comment: @elclanrs I tried adding "--source-map foo", but no map was generated. I am using AngularJS, but I've isolated the problem to a single JS file, so I'm not including any libraries in the uglification. It's just "uglify app/foo.js --source-map foo"

Comment: See https://github.com/btford/ngmin

Comment: @elclanrs thanks, but that's not my problem. This is code that I've been working on for weeks,so the all the Angular Min stuff was taken care of a long time ago. See my next comment...

Comment: Purely by chance, I deleted a "debugger;" line and now it's minifying.  But my question stands, how do I get from the Uglify error to deleting a "debugger;" at line 1571 in my source

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was the final line of one of the files didn't end with a CR. Thus, it and the first line on the following file were being concatenated into a single line.